# Remote Tensorboard not working with SSH tunnel

Tags: tensorflow, ssh, tensorflow2.0, tensorboard, ssh-tunnel

From home, I am trying to monitor a tensorflow training with Tensorboard which is running on my machine at work.
We have an ssh gateway to access to machines at work, so I have to make an ssh tunnel, and from what I saw on internet this is how to do it to connect with the default port of Tensorboard 6006:

`ssh -NfL 6006:remote_machine:6006 user@ssh_gateway_machine`

Then on the remote machine:

`tensorboard --logdir dir/ --port 6006`

Then on my machine at home:

`http://localhost:6006`

But the page is white and loading forever, it cannot retrieve the data.

When I am trying to monitor this same machine but from another machine at work, using port forwarding the same way (without ssh tunnel) works fine, so the problem is not comming from Tensorboard rather from the ssh tunnel I guess, but I cannot figure out why.

Answer (score 5):

Try using `bind_all` parameter while launching the tensorboard. It allows remote connection for tensorboard. So your command should be like

```
tensorboard --logdir dir/ --port 6006 --bind_all
```

reference : https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/blob/master/README.md#i-get-a-network-security-popup-every-time-i-run-tensorboard-on-a-mac

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but it still doesn't work...still loading with nothing appearing

Comment: @GabrielC Then I think that it should be related to port security, you should check if inward traffic allowed on the machine hosting tensorboard on port 6006.

Answer (score 2):

I agree, you have to execute with bind_all option :

```
tensorboard --logdir dir/ --port 6006 --bind_all
```

But, maybe in your case, you have to just check if the `ssh_gateway_machine` ssh server is configured to allow port forwarding : `AllowTcpForwarding yes` ?

Explanations here :

- https://www.ssh.com/ssh/tunneling/example
- https://www.ssh.com/ssh/sshd_config/

Example :

```
ssh user@ssh_gateway_machine
sudo -i
vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

If possible (ask your company IT security staff), edit lines :

```
AllowTcpForwarding yes
```

But in my case, instead of `-L` option executed locally, I had to make a ssh remote port forwarding `-R` option executed remotely (on `remote_machine`) because I cannot access from internet directly to any ports of `remote_machine` network.

So, I think my `-R` remote port forwarding method is better, if your `remote_machine` have access to internet and you can install/activate a ssh server (on a NAS or on your `local_machine`).

So, I repeat, it is done with : `-R` option executed on `remote_machine`.

So, the `ssh_gateway_machine` become local (Synology NAS for instance).

If you don't have a NAS, maybe it could be your `local_machine` if you install/activate a SSH server. (`ssh_gateway_machine` == `local_machine`)

And you have to modify Port forwarding of your internet provider box/ network router) to forward ssh incoming port to your internal `ssh_gateway_machine` (to be able to have incoming access from internet through your internet provider box up to your `ssh_gateway_machine`.

You have to check and modify server ssh config in the `ssh_gateway_machine` (Synology NAS),`GatewayPorts`  & `AllowTcpForwarding` options :

```
ssh user@ssh_gateway_machine
sudo -i
vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Edit lines :

```
GatewayPorts yes
AllowTcpForwarding yes
```

Also, don't forget to modify Firewall rules of `ssh_gateway_machine` to accept only ssh incoming access from `remote_machine` public IP.
Maybe it can also be done on your internet router.

After, you have to execute from `remote_machine` :

```
ssh user@ssh_gateway_machine_public_ip -R 6006:localhost:6006
```

with `ssh_gateway_machine_public_ip` = `local_machine_public_ip` = `internet_box public_ip`

Picture of the network : 
[My network map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dSXx.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was running tensorboard on ubuntu using `tensorboard --logdir=runs` and I was getting the forever loading screen at `http://localhost:6008`

I had ran the command several times and every time it had spun a new port so the port that I was trying to access was being used by an orphan tensorboard leading to the forever loading screen.

What ended up working for me was

`kill -9 <pid_my_old_tensorboards>`

and running a fresh tensorboard using

`tensorboard --logdir=runs --port 6008`